# RichTextBox scrollbar image as background c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, background, richtextbox

I want to have image as background in my richtextbox command.
I'm using, but I can only set background value to already defined colors, not images. (I were using scrollbarviewer but it doesnt show in my richtextbox)

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="880" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="#FFA02626" Background="{x:Null}">
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value can be any object, so it can be an ImageBrush. You can do it with the element syntax.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="285" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="880" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="#FFA02626" Background="{x:Null}">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="cool-northern-lights-pic-4.jpg"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="some.jpg"/>
    </RichTextBox.Background>
</RichTextBox>
```

See if this helps.